# Worrying about cross browser compatibility

Tags: visualforce, bestpractice

Do we have to worry about rendering our salesforce custom page to different browser? If so, what are the things needed and to consider to solve or to have good practice developing a custom page without worrying that your page may not rendered properly in different browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With each [release](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_included_release_notes.htm) Salesforce provide compatibility details. You can see in release notes about browser compatibility and plan accordingly.
Right now current release is winter '15 and you can check about browser compatibility [here](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_supported_browsers_cheatsheet.pdf)

In addition, you can check for [known issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?tag=User%20Interface) always.

If you are an HTML, CSS expert and know their standard implementation then use all standards here because visulaforce follow all those standards strictly, also I would recommend to use open source UI frameworks ex: Bootstrap. It will solve you various rendering issues. HTML, CSS can be a never ending discussion so it depends person to person. If you follow all html doc type standards then various problems can be erased.

Also, always set "doctype" attribute in `<apex:page>` to get expected result. It seems useless and ignored by most but it prevent form various unexpected results when testing cross browser.

In terms of IE9 or earlier you have to use workarounds for various things like ajax class, popups etc. Salesforce is going to remove support for IE8 and earlier from Summer '15 so develop pages accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you expect your pages to be used by the medical profession (e.g. hospitals are well-known for not upgrading OS versions because it will break their software), you should most likely just code in standards-compliant HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript. By ignoring the minority, you'll produce code much faster and still support the majority of Internet users.

Avoid working towards pixel-perfect renditions, as it is virtually impossible to cover every possible design on every possible browser with 100% pixel for pixel compatibility. In fact, the modern mantra is to use dynamic design (e.g. media queries, percentages, scalable values) to simultaneously support mobile devices of varying dimensions as well as web browsers.

I personally develop my code in Google Chrome, and use it's "emulator" mode to check my pages on a variety of virtual devices, such as phones, tablets, and desktops, to make sure my design is usable across all browsers. Pixel-perfect design is only an afterthought, since it is difficult to get your own elements to look consistent, and impossible to get standard Visualforce elements, such as buttons and links, to look consistent across browsers (because not even Salesforce's core UI renders the same across browsers).